# Url redirection to a path with "de" for new Mailing

Tags: mailing, localisation

I have a CiviCRM (5.55.1) running on Drupal (9.4.8). The language ist set to German.

When I click "Neues Rundschreiben" aka "New Mailing", the URL of that menu item is https://MyHost/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new but then it redirects me to https://MyHost/**de**/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new. This give a Page not found error. If I remove the **"de"** from path, all works as expected.

This site does not use Mosaica and it does not have Multi-Language enabled.

It seems the only menu entry with this behavior.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Are you in multilingual mode, or single-language German?

Comment: On a single language CiviCRM (5.50.4) and Multi-Language Drupal (9.4.8.) I do not experience any problems with or without the "de" in the path. If your problem persists maybe check your version of the mosaico extension and add it to the question as well.

Comment: This site does not use Mosaica and it does not have Multi-Language enabled.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and could resolve it by disabling the language detection by url in Drupal: /admin/config/regional/language/detection

The reason however is most liekly a bug with Moasaico which saves the complete URL including Drupal's language prefix liek this: domain/prefix/url-path

Some "static files" CiviCRM/Mosaico uses can currently only be used if the urls are saved without the language prefix.